# How to add jar files in WAR WEB-INF/lib, when skinny-wars is used?

Tags: java, maven, maven-ear-plugin

I have two WAR files inside an EAR file. I use skinny wars (maven-ear-plugin) so that all common jar files of the WARs are added in the root lib directory of the EAR file. In this case, the WEB-INF/lib of both WARs are empty.
However, there are two other jar files which I need to place in the WEB-INF/lib of the WARs.

The jar1.jar inside the WEB-INF/lib of the first WAR.
The jar2.jar inside the WEB-INF/lib of the second WAR.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Without pom file, JDK version etc. log file issue or alike it's more or less impossible to make even an educated guess...